# XNA 4.0 Drawing inside of Cylinder model

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

im making a simple XNA game and i have stuck trying to make the surrounding of my world. Atm i have a flat terrain on which im playing . I want to put around a big cylinder with a texture around  it . SO from the terrain i will be able to see the texture on the inside of the cylinder.I have tried changing Culling settings but it eather didnt work or i did it wrong . Any suggestions on how my draw method should be ? Do i need a model specially made to be displayed from inside ? 
Any code or point to tutorial will help (i have tried a lot already).
Thanks.

A sample of my last attempt.

```
private void DrawBackground(Model model)
         {

             RasterizerState stat = new RasterizerState();
             stat.CullMode = CullMode.None; 


             foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
             {
                 foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                 {
                     effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                     effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
                     effect.World = Matrix.Identity;

                     // Use the matrices provided by the game camera
                     effect.View = gameCamera.ViewMatrix;
                     effect.Projection = gameCamera.ProjectionMatrix;
                 }
                 mesh.Draw();
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to remember where I had seen a textured cylinder before, and then I stumbled across it on the MSDN site http://create.msdn.com.

[Shader series - 2](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shader_series_2)